# FreeNAS/TrueNAS NFS v4 mount timeout from client

Tags: mount, nfs

Have a Free/TrueNAS appliance happily serving up SMB/AFP, but not so happy with NFS =(

TrueNAS setup:

- [X] Enable NFSv4
- [ ] NFSv3 ownership model for NFSv4
- [ ] Require Kerberos for NFSv4
- [ ] Server UDP NFS clients
- [X] Allow non-root mount
- [ ] Support >16 groups
- [ ] Log mountd(8) requests
- [ ] Log rpc.statd(8) and rpc.lockd(8)

*(same result with "Enable NFSv4" checked/unchecked)*

I've added a single NFS share, with default settings
The same user *(UID/GID)* exists on both the server/client
Setting the below, within `fstab`, to allow mounting from non-root:

```
192.168.1.50:/mnt/tank/bob                           /mnt/nfs/bob  nfs    defaults 0 0
```

Issuing the following results in a timeout:

```
% mount -vvv 192.168.1.50:/mnt/tank/bob /mnt/nfs/bob 
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jan 14 17:26:42 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.50,clientaddr=192.168.1.51'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

I've also added `/etc/host` entries on both machines:
*server:*
`192.168.1.51 myhost myhost.mydomain.com`
*client:*
`192.168.1.50 serverhost serverhost.mydomain.com`

From the client, `nfs-ls` can list the contents on the share just fine:

```
nfs-ls nfs://192.168.1.50/mnt/tank/bob                         
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          212 .rhosts
-rw-------  1  1234  1234         1572 .history
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          983 .cshrc
-rw-------  1  1234  1234           37 .lesshst
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          782 .shrc
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          301 .mail_aliases
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          267 .mailrc
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234           91 .login_conf
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          881 .profile
-rw-r--r--  1  1234  1234          323 .login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr;**
Just needed to set `noresvport` in `/etc/fstab` for the nfs mount

---

Re-set everything back up, following TrueNAS docs, [here](https://www.truenas.com/docs/hub/sharing/nfs/nfs-share/). *(basically, just revert to nfsv3)*

Again, I was able to `nfs-ls ...` and the contents displayed just fine, a `mount request succeeded from...` log entry promptly displayed within `/var/log/messages`, as well.

I noticed these would pop-up in the logs when attempting to mount:

```
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,proto=tcp,timeo=50,noresvport,addr=10.10.10.10'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.10.10.10 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.10.10.10 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 774
```

Seemed to be hanging on the `port 774` line, until the client timed-out.

Ended up being the lame `noresvport` option.

```
10.10.10.10:/path/to/mnt /local/path nfs nfsvers=3,proto=tcp,timeo=50,noresvport,rw,relatime,user,noauto 0 0
```